# Frameless Dialog in Java

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

I want to display an image when my swing application starts, 
It will flash for 2 seconds and then dispose the dialog
I will set the size of the image to the size of dialog

Is there any way to have a frame-less dialog or any other similar component ?

thanks in advance !

Comment: Or use a "native" splash screen: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/SplashScreen.html

Answer (score 4):

If you are ussing swing:

```
dialog.setUndecorated(true);
```

If you are using JavaFx:

```
stage.initStyle(StageStyle.UNDECORATED);
```

Comment: he is not using JavaFX.. the question is tagged as `swing`

Comment: Well, he also gave the option to do it with `swing` so there's no need to downvote.

Answer (score 1):

Use a dialog with `setUndecorated( true )`